# Unable to change auto punctuate setting to off

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I want to set `text_auto_punctuate` in Android to off in order to remove two spaces changing into a period in the soft keyboard. I'm using the following line which for some reason is not working and has left me stumped:

```
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_AUTO_PUNCTUATE, 0);
```

I'm calling this in my `onCreate()` function call for my service that starts up everything in my app. For some reason however even with the line above when I do a double space in the soft keyboard Android is still converting it to a period.

What am I doing wrong? I'm stuck..